# Hard drive access denied from Windows Explorer (but works from command prompt as Admin)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, permissions, acl

When I try to access a hard drive from Windows Explorer (in Windows 7), I keep getting this error:

> E:\ is not accessible. Access is denied.

I am logged in under an admin account. Oddly, when I start command prompt (`cmd.exe`) as Admin, I can work with the drive normally (list and open files). When `cmd.exe` is started normally, it does not work. Running Windows Explorer as admin does not help.

Searching the net yielded suggestions to take ownership of the files, but that does not seem to work (they already appear to be owned by me). The problem occurred after a fresh Windows 7 install (upgrade from RC to RTM).

Answer (score 2):

"an admin" account is NOT the same as 'run as administrator'. the former is a user account with administrator privileges, the latter will run programs from the built-in (and hidden) adminstrator account.

you will have to take ownership for the user name you're logged on with.